# How to read/write to secondary member of a MongoDB replica-set?

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I am currently planning some server infrastructure. I have two servers in different locations. My apps (apis and stuff) are running on both of them. The client connects to the nearest (best connection). In case of failure of one server the other can process the requests. I want to use mongodb for my projects. The first idea is to use a replica set, therefore I can ensure the data is consistent. If one server fails the data is still accessible and the secondary switches to primary. When the app on the primary server wants to use the data, it is fine, but the other server must connect to to the primary server in order to handle data (that would solve the failover, but not the "best connection" problem). In Mongodb there is an option to read data from secondary servers, but then I have to ensure, that the inserts (only possible on primary) are consistent on every secondary. There is also an option for this "writeConcern". Is it possible to somehow specify “writeConcern on specific secondary”? Because If an add a second secondary without the apps on it, "writeConcern" on every secondary would not be necessary. And if I specify a specific value I don't really know on which secondary the data is available, right ?

Summary: I want to reduce the connections between the servers when the api is called.

[image: scheme]

Please share some thought or Ideas to fix my problem.

Comment: _"If one server fails the data is still accessible and the secondary switches to primary."_ In a two node replica-set, it is not possible. First of all it takes a majority of two to elect a primary (in case of a failure). Take a look at [Primary-Secondary-Arbiter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-architecture-three-members/index.html#primary-with-a-secondary-and-an-arbiter-psa). See this post [Does a replica-set with two members make sense?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/148855/does-a-replica-set-with-only-two-machines-make-sense).

Comment: Ok, your are right. I need at least 3 servers, but the question is still the same.

Comment: The application always connects to _a_ replica-set - not a specific member of a replica-set. The primary replicates data to to other members (and all members are connected). When a member (primary) fails, an election takes place among the remaining two members and a new primary is elected. So, the application connects to the newly elected primary to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writes can only be done on primaries.

To control which secondary the reads are directed to, you can use [max staleness](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference-staleness/) as well as tags.

> that the inserts (only possible on primary) are consistent on every secondary.

I don't understand what you mean by this phrase.

If you have two geographically separated datacenters, A and B, it is physically impossible to write data in A and instantly see it in B. You must either wait for the write to propagate or wait for the read to fetch data from the remote node.

To pay the cost at write time, set your write concern to the number of nodes in the deployment (2, in your proposal).  To pay the cost at read time, use primary reads.

Note that merely setting write concern equal to the number of nodes doesn't make all nodes have the same data at all times  - it just makes your application only consider the write successful when all nodes have received it. The primary can still be ahead of a particular secondary in terms of operations committed.

And, as noted in comments, a two-node replica set will not accept writes unless both members are operational, which is why it is generally not a useful configuration to employ.

> Summary: I want to reduce the connections between the servers when the api is called.

This has nothing to do with the rest of the question, and if you *really* mean this it's a premature optimization.

If what you want is faster network I/O I suggest looking into setting up better connectivity between your application and your database (for example, I imagine AWS would offer pretty good connectivity  between their various regions).